# How to make button change paragraph more than once and in last one change both paragraph and button text?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I really need help with my research project:
How to add more paragraphs to change on the click of the button like "Third Paragraph" and "Forth Paragraph" and in the last click the (Forth Paragraph) I want to change the paragraph and button text together, the paragraph to another text and the button from (click) to (Hint)?

```js
var time = 0;

function changeText(txt) {
    var txt = (time === 0) ? "First Paragraph" : "Second Paragraph";
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
    time++;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>
        <b id='name'>{description}</b>.
    </p>

    <input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value="click" />
    <br /><br />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this snippet may help you

```js
let time = 0;
const paragraphs = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];

function changeText() {
  let text = `${paragraphs[time]} Paragraph`;
  if (text === "Fourth Paragraph") {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "another text";
    document.getElementById('btn').value = "Hint"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = text;
  }
  if (paragraphs[time + 1]) {
    time++;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><b id='name'>{description}</b>.</p>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value="click" id="btn" />
<br /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks, man YOU! Solve the problem. 

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please answer the question when you use answers. "Try this" answers are not useful since they don't actually answer the question. Adding a simple explanation would make this answer perfect and very easy for beginners to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`JS`

```
    var index = 0;
    var arr = ["First Paragraph","Second Paragraph","Third Paragraph","Forth Paragraph"];
    function changeText(element){  
    
    if(index < arr.length){
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = arr[index];
    }else{
    element.style.display = "none";
    }
       index++;
    }
```

`HTML`

```
    <body>
    <p> <b id='name'>{description}</b>.
      </p>
     
      <input type='button' onclick='changeText(this)' value="click"/>
     <br /><br />
    </body>
```

You can use arr and index value to set text or button hide

**Try This**

Comment: Thanks, man you are awesome.
but not hide the button it's changing the text of the button to (Hint).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please answer the question when you use answers. "Try this" answers are not useful since they don't actually answer the question. Adding a simple explanation would make this answer perfect and very easy for beginners to understand.